# Why Windows API 5 error when running initexmf in MiKTeX?

Tags: installing, miktex

I have a MiKTeX installation running on Windows Vista, and whenever I try to run initexmf, I get the following error message

initexmf: Windows API error 5: Access is denied.
initexmf: Data: C:\Users\Public\Documents\My Music

The strange thing is, I don't have any latex documents in the My Music folder. Does anyone know what the problem might be? I don't have this problem on Windows XP computers, and I have tried disabling UAC, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem by including the --admin flag.

```
initexmf --admin
```

works

Comment: But with the --admin switch you are calling a different tool. E.g. initexmf --admin -u will (as far as I know) not update the FNDB of your local tree. At my opinion you should really try to find out, what's going on e.g. by setting a trace: http://miktex.org/diagnosing. Btw: I sometimes get API-errors when miktex options is open in the background.

Comment: @Ulrike: yeah, it sometimes mo.exe will lock the fndbs for some reason :-(